# InstagramAPI posting error 429, 400

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I recently installed the python [InstagramAPI](https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python/), and I tried posting an image to my acccount, when I run the program, this is displayed.

> Request return 429 error!
> Login success!
>
> Request return 400 error!

And the image doesn't post. My code is below, can anyone offer any advice/help/alternative code?

```
#import imageio
#imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI
user,pwd = 'testUser', 'iStillThinkPasswordIsTheBestPassword'

InstagramAPI = InstagramAPI(user,pwd)
InstagramAPI.login() # login

photo_path ='C:/Users/ted67/Important/Untitled.png'
caption    = "Testing web automation. Don't mind this."
InstagramAPI.uploadPhoto(photo_path, caption = caption)
```

Comment: Is that your actual password? Might want to edit that out.

Comment: https://httpstatuses.com/429

Comment: +pycoder I'm such an idiot I forgot lmao. Edited and changed on Instagram. Been meaning to change it anyway

Comment: +Matthew Daly I understand what they are, I'm just looking at how I can fix it. It shouldn't be sending too many requests.